# Bind AWK TCP connection to certain IP

Tags: linux, tcp, awk, ip, gawk

```
/inet/tcp/80/0/0
```

Port 80 is already in use by eth0:1 (lighttpd server) but I'd like to bind my AWK process on eth0.

Is there any way you can define IP on which to bind AWK process?

Comment: @larsmans GNU Awk 3.1.6 on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround would be to use "netcat -l -p 80 -s you.ip.number" within AWK.